# Create Cocoapod that uses a .plist in main project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, info.plist

I am writing a `Cocoapod` that will need to read some config values from the app running it.

I was hoping I could create something like `Config.plist` in my app project and have my `Cocoapod` read it something like....

`private lazy var config: [String: String] = parseConfig()`

```
private func parseConfig() -> [String: String] {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MyConfig", ofType: "plist"), let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] {
            return dict
        }
        return [:]
    }
```

I could then reference the values elsewhere in code like `self.config["clientId"]!` and so on.

However when building my app and trying to invoke a value that requires the config, I am getting

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Which to me suggests it cannot find the file.

Should I do something extra to have my pod read from a `.plist` in the installing app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a custom `.pist` file, including into the main app project then referencing it from the `cocoapod` and your code worked fine.

`myConfig.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>testString</key>
    <string>Test</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`cocoapod` `View Controller`:

```swift
    private lazy var config: [String: String] = parseConfig()

    private func parseConfig() -> [String: String] {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myConfig", ofType: "plist"), let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] {
            return dict
        }
        return [:]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(config["testString"])
    }
```

Output:

```
Optional("Test")
```

Check if `myConfig.plist` file is well formatted and if it is included into the main app target

Comment: It was being added to the wrong target, silly mistake, thank you so much